# How to get object values as type in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

could someone please tell be how to get the values of an object as type? I have something like this:

```
const MY_CONST = Object.freeze({
     main: 'website' as 'website',
     admin: 'backoffice' as 'backoffice'
});
```

Then I have a function that accepts one of these values

```
const myFunc = (channel: MY_TYPE): MY_TYPE {
    // something
};
```

Basically how do we extract values from an object to have something like this without manually writing every property from object?

```
type MY_TYPE = MY_CONST.main | MY_CONST.admin;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Might be a more concise method, but you can use `keyof typeof MY_CONST` to get the keys of the object, and look up those keys on the `MY_CONST` type:

```
type MY_TYPE = typeof MY_CONST[keyof typeof MY_CONST];
```

Also note that when you have lots of properties, `as const` on the object is easier than using `as` on each property:

```
const MY_CONST = Object.freeze({
     main: 'website',
     admin: 'backoffice'
} as const);
```

Comment: Your solution "typeof MY_CONST[keyof typeof MY_CONST]" is very elegant.